# K3D Kubeconfig invalid credentials

Tags: kubeconfig, k3d

My Kube is running since almost 6 month, and yet I get `Invalid Credentials` response while trying to connect to it.

It runs on a K3D instance, has access to the root host, as well the 3 containers, LB, agent, server.

How can I get this connection back or any clue why the credentials suddenly went invalid without having to destroy the current setup?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe the certificates expired